I notice the book 1 Maccabees isn't part of the Jewish canon even though the basis for Hanukkah is
As far as I know, Hanukkah is about the Maccabean Revolt. The book of 1 Maccabees is deuterocanonical in Catholicism & some Orthodox churches but not in Jewish canon. So, according to the Jewish tradition, Hannukah isn't based on a religious text? Is Hanukkah a Jewish-in-ethnicity holiday rather than a Jewish-in-religion holiday?

Maccabees isn't part of the Jewish canon because it was written long after there weren't any prophets (in fact, that's the explanation for why Shimon b. Matthias was made regent of the Jewish people, as stated in Maccabees). But that doesn't mean it can't be used as a source for history. Likewise, the Talmud isn't biblical canon but is very central to Judaism. However, Chanukah for the past 1500 years at least has been more than anything, based on traditions rather than the historiography presented in Maccabees.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12275/which-talmudic-source-for-%E1%B8%A4anukah-is-the-real-source

Is 'Shimon b. Matthias' = 'Shimon ben Boethus' ?

@Harel13 so 1 Maccabees IS used a source for history?

The religious text that serves as a basis is the Talmud,  and / or megillat taanit.

It's obviously also non-canonical, but the Christian scriptures mentioned the event 2000 years ago: "… in Jerusalem at the time of Hanukkah, the Festival of Dedication", John 10:22 (NLT).

@BCLC not at all b. Boethus. This is who I was referring to: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Thassi. And Maccabees has been and is used as a source of history by Jews, though perhaps not too commonly until ca. the early 20th century. Nowadays many hypothesize that it was originally in Hebrew and it's possible that in Late Antiquity and/or the early Islamic period Jews still had access to that original version.

The Jewish Bible ends shortly after they've rebuilt the Second Temple.
The next truly canonical work of Jewish faith is the Talmud (whose first stage was edited and compiled around 1800 years ago), and that does discuss Chanukah quite clearly. As it's in that religious text, it's very much a religious holiday.

ok thanks. quick follow up: are there jewish-in-ethnicity holidays?

Very interesting question @BCLC! In the religious sphere, perhaps Purim (in as much as all Jews would have died if not for the events celebrated on Purim), and certainly in Israel, Israeli Independence day and (Israeli) Holocaust Remembrance day.

@BCLC That's not a term we use. What do you mean?

@N.T., I think it means holidays other than those commanded in the Torah, Hanukkah and Purim being the two most obvious. Similarly, the North American Thanksgivings are non-religious holidays that feel like they should be a religious holiday (or at least it used to).

@N.T. I'm not sure if there's such a distinction between ethnic & religious holidays, which is part of my question.
